# Checking a password with Zend_Auth

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, passwords

How i can check a password, when i am already authorized on my page? I need write an action, where the user will change a password, and i must check a current his password. When I using a following code:

```
$this->authAdapter->setIdentity($identity);
    $this->authAdapter->setCredential($credential);
    if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($this->authAdapter)){...}
```

then my current session disappears... How i can check password belonging to logged user?

Answer (score 1):

That's the `authenticate` method of the Zend_Auth instance is doing two things: checks the credentials are valid and store them. If you only want to check if the credentials are valid, directly call the adapter `authenticate` method:

```
$this->authAdapter->authenticate();
```

Comment: But how i can do it? I have a variable with password and how i can check, if this password match to password in database..?

Comment: In the code you pasted, just change the `if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($this->authAdapter))` to `if($this->authAdapter->authenticate())`

Comment: Ok sorry, it worked, so authenticate(); is a method that belongs to adapter, not to auth. Thanks @Guillaume